# What is the issue that is causing Payload Error in JWT using Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I want to authorise an API using login token using JWT but when i run the code it gives me invalid payload error.I have already added necessary modules that needed to be added.

This is for a project that i am doing for a college purposes my idea is for a social site

```
def post(self, request):
    token = request.headers['authorization']

    data = {'token': token}

    payload_decoded = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        valid_data = VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer().validate(data)
        user_id = valid_data['user']

    except ValidationError as v:
        print("validation error", v)

    serializer = InstructorDetailsSerializer(data = request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i am receiving payload error and want to actually resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace please?

Comment: Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
token eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6ImZkZDAyMWNhLTZlMTgtNGZhOC1hNmU5LTA3ZTJjOWI3OGQ5ZiIsImV4cCI6MTU3MTIxOTE3MH0.awp_iYZ12FYNkDP2rxEisjctrSdst8VzL0WEKmVJMfA
data {'token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6ImZkZDAyMWNhLTZlMTgtNGZhOC1hNmU5LTA3ZTJjOWI3OGQ5ZiIsImV4cCI6MTU3MTIxOTE3MH0.awp_iYZ12FYNkDP2rxEisjctrSdst8VzL0WEKmVJMfA'}
Bad Request: /inst_details
[17/Aug/2019 09:55:22] "POST /inst_details HTTP/1.1" 400 31